# Jquery draggable attach to new container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div inside a parent div that users can drag from dropbox to final_dest.  Users can also create new items with a button click.  The button click appends the new div to dropbox.

```
<div id='#dropbox'>
      <div id='item_1'>Some Item</div>
</div>

<div id='final_dest'></div>
```

If a user drags item_1 to another container, how can i remove it from dropbox and put it in final_dest?

```
            $('#item_'+a).draggable({ // make this whole damn thing draggable
                    drag:function(event){
                            helper:"clone",
                            jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
                    },
                    stop:function(event,ui){
                                    $('this').detach('#dropbox');
                                    $('this').append('final_dest');

                    }

            });
```

I have tried using detach but can not figure out how to remove it from dropbox div.

The problem is if a user drags item_1 to final_dest, and then creates a new item_2 div,  it appears below item_1's spot in dropbox. i am trying to get it to appear where item_1 did.  It does this, because item_1 is not removed from dropbox.

[image]

Comment: You need to give more details. I tried to recreate the situation on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uxepwhb/), but I don't see any way for a phantom `item_1` to exist. Could you create a runnable stack snippet that exemplifies the problem?

Comment: Yes I can in a few hours. Basically the point is, when I create a new div it appears in grey box.  If I drag it across screen, and then create another new div, I want that new div to appears in grey box.  Not below where first div was...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to gather your origin and destination elements, call the detach, set css, and call your append on the drop event attached to your containers like so:

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable", drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});
```

Full working example can be found here for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/gdkx7861/1/